# Custom Page in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: application-pages

Sorry guys, I believe, I have framed my question in wrong way. Let me put that here now.

I am supposed to implement the automation of listing of jobs on our intranet. We will have two types of jobs (both internal and external). So, I have to merge these two types and display them in a web page (with same look and feel of the other pages). So, I have already merged both the type of job and able to create an XML file which contains the unique job listing. So, I want to bring this XML content in to a list and display in a webpage of sharepoint application. Would you be able to help me please to acheive this?

Comment: Why don't use a UserControl with grid in it within a webpart instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom application page using Visual Studio:

Drop a SPGridView:

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView ID="grdResults" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines ="None" AllowPaging="true" PageSize ="30" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" EnableViewState ="true" CssClass="mGrid"  PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"  AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt">                     
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Your column 1" HeaderText="Your column 1" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Your column 1" HeaderText="Your column 1" />
                </Columns>               
</SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

Bind the your datatable (retrieved from Database) with Grid using the following code:

```
                        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);                           
                        grdResults.PagerTemplate = null;
                        grdResults.TemplateControl = null;
                        grdResults.DataSource = dv;
                        grdResults.DataBind();
                        grdResults.Visible = true;
```

You're done!

Answer (score 0):

There is no Provision to add Application Page .aspx page using visual studio. Create a blank SharePoint application next add new item SharePoint module. This Module contains the sample.txt file to the desired .aspx file. And then pasting the markup inside the new file.

Please see this link for more referral

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Custom-application-pages-in-the-SharePoint-2010-Sandbox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you need to create an XML file for this (are the jobs coming from some external source)?  Just create a list with two content types - External Job and Internal Job.  Create a view that groups by content type.

If you *really* need that XML file format, create a Data View Web Part whose data source is the XML file.

You should try to avoid custom development when OOB features will do the job.

Comment: The main reason for creating XML is that, I have to fetch the job feeds from two different URLs. These URLs will give me the content in XML format.